# Why are my apache ignite cache put operations inconsistent in speed?

Tags: python, ignite, database-performance, in-memory-database

I am running a local apache ignite docker container with in the default configuration, storing all data into RAM. Writing larger base64 strings (~200kb) with the pyignite `cache.put()` operation into the cache takes around 6ms, which would perfectly satisfy my performance needs. But there are spikes every few put operations, which take around 50ms butchering the overall performance of my setup.
(The base64 encoded string contains image data produced by Microsoft AirSim.)

```
IgniteDataProducer::put                         5.98       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.06       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         45.11      ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         5.8        ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.14       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         50.69      ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.15       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.86       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         54.5       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         5.88       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.29       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         46.15      ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.44       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         6.05       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         50.29      ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         53.25      ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         5.68       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         5.87       ms
IgniteDataProducer::put                         53.89      ms
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to reduce these spikes?

Things I have tried:

- Running multiple ignite nodes
- allocating different amounts of memory to the JVM (from 4GB up to 24GB)
- trial & error with all the different cache settings
- Adjusting the GC (but the problem still exists even with EpsilonGC)
- Running the whole Setup on more powerful hardware (this reduced the 6ms -> 1ms and the spike length from 50ms -> 20 ms, but did not eliminate the spikes)
- installing pyignite with the C-extension

This is my current cache configuration:

```
SCENE_SCHEMA = {
    PROP_NAME: 'SQL_PUBLIC_SCENE',
    PROP_SQL_SCHEMA: 'PUBLIC',
    PROP_CACHE_MODE: 2,
    PROP_CACHE_ATOMICITY_MODE: 1,
    PROP_WRITE_SYNCHRONIZATION_MODE: 1,
    PROP_BACKUPS_NUMBER: 0,
    PROP_IS_ONHEAP_CACHE_ENABLED: True,
    PROP_REBALANCE_MODE: 1,
    PROP_QUERY_PARALLELISM: 2,
    PROP_PARTITION_LOSS_POLICY: 4,
    PROP_QUERY_ENTITIES: [
        {
            'table_name': 'SCENE',
            'key_field_name': 'TIMESTAMP',
            'key_type_name': 'java.lang.Long',
            'field_name_aliases': [],
            'query_fields': [
                {
                    'name': 'TIMESTAMP',
                    'type_name': 'java.lang.Long',
                    'is_key_field': True,
                    'is_notnull_constraint_field': True,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'SCENE_BINARY',
                    'type_name': 'byte[]',
                },
            ],
            'query_indexes': [],
            'value_type_name': 'SQL_PUBLIC_SCENE_TYPE',
            'value_field_name': None,
        },
    ],
}
```

JVM options for ignite:

```
-server
-Xms10g
-Xmx10g
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

versions:

```
python == 3.8.6
pyignite == 0.5.2
ignite docker image == 2.13.0
```

Any help or hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: How many nodes were used when you got those results? Is the python client connected to all of them or just one? See https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/python-thin-client#partition-awareness

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn I used one node on the same machine (as a docker container) for these results. The same results appeared when I used a dockerized 3-Node Setup (1 Client Node to which the python client is connected and 2 server nodes, i.e. without partition awareness).